# Spring, Hibernate retrieving simple user list from database on jsp page

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

i'm beginner with spring hibernate. Need to show users from database simple on jsp page with EL, got no errors, app started, classes mapped into database but nothing shows on jsp page, only table "User Name" from th. Maybe input or anotations are wrong cant see, don't know. Table in MySQL database is user with two users already inside. Thank You

users jsp page

```html
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<%@include file="/WEB-INF/view/header.jsp" %>

<table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>User Name</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <c:forEach items="${users}" var="user">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <c:out value="${user.name}"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
    </tbody>
</table>

<%@include file="/WEB-INF/view/footer.jsp" %>
```

Controller

```html
@Controller
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @RequestMapping("/users")
    public String users(Model model){
        List<User> users = userService.getUserList();
        model.addAttribute("users", users);
        return "users";
    }

}
```

UserDao

```html
@Transactional
@Repository
public class UserDao {

    @Autowired
    SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public List<User> getUserList() throws NullPointerException {
        List<User> userList = null;
        try {
            Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
            String hql = "FROM com.hellospringdemo.model.User";
            Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
            userList = query.list();
            session.flush();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return userList;

    }
}
Tried with this also same show's nothing...
Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
List<User> result = session.createCriteria(User.class).list();
return result;
```

UserService from interface

```html
@Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

    @Autowired
    private UserDao userDao;

    public List<User> getUserList() {
        return userDao.getUserList();
    }
}
```

UserService interface

```html
public interface UserService {

    List<User> getUserList();
}
```

Dispatcher

```html
<context:component-scan base-package="com.hellospringdemo"/>

    
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>

   
    <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/view/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    </bean>
```

AppContext.xml

```html
<context:component-scan base-package="com.hellospringdemo"/>

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/blog"/>
        <property name="username" value="root"/>
        <property name="password" value=""/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>

        <property name="packagesToScan">
            <list>
                <value>com.hellospringdemo</value>
            </list>
        </property>

    </bean>


    
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven/>


    <bean id="userDao" class="com.hellospringdemo.model.UserDao"/>
    

</beans>
```

Comment: are you tried the debug first to see if the dao retrieve the data?

Comment: have you mapped the view resolvers?

Comment: its show's name = null , don't know why :(
just a sec...

Comment: Don't catch Exception, don't throw NullPointerException, and make sure you have committed the changes in your database when you inserted the 2 users.

Comment: @JBNizet If l delete that NullPointer its ok same but if delete try catch , got error
org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not obtain transaction-synchronized Session for current thread

Comment: Then fix that error. Catching the exception and hiding it won't fix the problem. Your spring configuration regarding transactions must be wrong.

Comment: @JBNizet Check AppContext in post on bottom and dispatcher, not sure if problem is with configuration

Comment: You have two contexts, one root for the services, DAOs, etc., and one child context for the MVC part. The child context must NOT scan the classes that are part of the root context. Put the controller in a separate package from the rest, and only scan this package in the child MVC context.

Comment: @JBNizet Works mate! Thank you , l changed in Dispatcher servlet package scan to controller only. In AppContext l left whole package scan, now works, thx once more :)